# How do you make Android Studio automatically include the proguard mapping file in a signed bundle?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently switched to uploading bundles instead of .apk files to Google Play. I'd like to include the mapping.txt file in the bundle automatically so I don't have to keep uploading them separately every time. It appears that this can be done automatically (search [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) for "ProGuard") but I couldn't find instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The process is indeed automaticallly done, you do not need to upload the mapping file separately.
AndroidStudio puts the mapping file in your bundle's BUNDLE-METADATA/com.android.tools.obfuscation folder. After generating the bundle there should be a proguard.map file inside.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.